# Execute hidden process in Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c++, windows-mobile

I have a test.exe that need to be called in my main application and run in the background (my main app must stay on top). 
I know we can use CreateProcess with hide option in MFC, but in windows mobile library the startupinfo is unavailable.

So does anyone have an idea how to do ?
Besides, is there any way that we can load and execute test.exe in the memory so that user can't see it in the running program dropdown list?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you need that? Are you going to write some sort of virus?

Comment: no, i'm not a virus maker. In fact the test.exe is a program that allow to update the value in some registers which i'll use in my main app. I didn't know how to update it myself that's why i need test.exe run in the background to update. That's all :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "running programs" list is simply an enumeration of top-level Window captions.  If your app a) has no windows or b) clears teh caption text, it will not show up.

Bear in mind, however, that this is the behavior of the default "running programs" control panel applet.  Many WinMo OEMs deliver a separate Task Manager application.  These work however the OEM wanted them too, but typically they actually list running processes.  You cannot hide those.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
If it's impossible to hide a process, do you know how to make the process minimized in C++ (Windows Mobile) so that i always stay in my main app ?

Thanks

Comment: @kingo: I don't understand.  Don't create a Window if you don't want one.  Just run from WinMain, main or whatever entry point you defined.

Comment: The thing is "test.exe" is a already existed file (i've renamed), not me who create, that's why i can't just call a part of it, i must run it in order to get what i wanted, and it's a win32 dialog base i think. So do you have any suggestion ?

Thank you!